# Automatically login user determined by IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I want to determine which IP the user is behind, and if it matches a specific
address which is the local network, the user should be logged in.

It should work with something like this, and wouldn't somewhere in global.asax be the right place for that?

```
if (Request.UserHostAddress.ToString() == "89.67.88.68")
{
  System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser("<someDefaultUsername>", "<someDefaultPassword>");    
}
```

Could anybody help where to place the method?

Best regards.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this, it is not very secure as it is trivial to change your IP.

Comment: A custom OWIN layer would that will run before auth would be ideal for this, but I would like to point that @BenRobinson is very right in that it is a very bad thing to do with regards to security.

Comment: Ben -> Is there a better more secure alternative? The users don't want to login when they're "inside" the building.

Comment: Use Windows authentication instead of forms authentication. Problem solved?

Comment: Use firewall to filter requests by IP. Don't rely on `Request.UserHostAddress` as it can be fudged. BTW "89.67.88.68" is not local IP address, it's an external.

Comment: Use IP-restrictions: http://forums.iis.net/t/1153158.aspx?How+to+restrict+a+IIS7+web+site+to+a+specific+range+of+IP+address+

Comment: Hi - it is an externally hosted solution, so is it possible then?